# Change boolean field in JModelList table like "published"

Tags: joomla-3.x, jmodel

Joomla 3.9.10.

I have custom component. In admin panel I show items list from one DB table with JModelList.

`models/mycom.php`:

```
class MyComModelMyCom extends JModelList {

  public function getItems() {
    ...
    return $items;
  }
}
```

`views/mycom/tmpl/default.php`:

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_mycom&view=mycom" method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><?= JHtml::_('grid.checkall') ?></th>
        <th><?= JText::_('COM_MYCOM_TITLE') ?></th>
        <th><?= JText::_('COM_MYCOM_MYBOOLEAN') ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php if (!empty($this->items)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->title ?></td>
            <td><?= $item->myboolean ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="task" value=""/>
  <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value=""/>
  <?= JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

There is one field with type 'boolean'. I want to change value from list table like standard field 'published'.

How can I do it? Is there any magic class in JHtml? Or what should I look for?

Comment: You want to translate `$item->myboolean` to `published` or `unpublished` based on the true|false boolean value?

Comment: I guess you mean the Toggle functionality. Right?.

Comment: @Ivan What exactly does "_I want to change value from list table like standard field 'published'._" mean?  Please describe what you seek differently.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL offers BOOLEAN data types via `TINYINT(1) which means it is storing zeros and ones.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean/)

Regardless of if you are evaluating `true`|`1` versus `false`|`0`, you are still dealing with truthy versus falsey values.

PHP offers loose comparisons so you don't need to be specific about the data type when writing a conditional.

If you just want to translate the column value as `published` or `unpublished`, here is a simple inline condition (ternary) technique:

```
<?= $item->myboolean ? 'published' : 'unpublished' ?>
```

Of course if you want language flexibility, you could write all-caps language placeholders and leverage your language .ini files.